# List all commits in a branch until a tag (including)

Tags: git, bitbucket

In a branch I have added 4 files in 4 different individual commits. Each commit has one file. Below is the example commit messages

Ex:

```
  Adding file 1 
  Adding file 2  ---test-tag
  Adding file 3
  Adding file 4
```

I have tagged the second commit with a tag named "test-tag". I want to list all the commits in this branch starting from the tag (including the commit containing the tag) to the latest commit in the branch. The list of commits should include the commit that is tagged as well. With the below commit I am getting the commits from the tag but not including it.

```
git log --pretty=oneline test-tag..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most Git commands, the two-dot `..` notation means *excluding the commit named on the left* as you've seen.  (The enumeration of all commits starts with the commit named on the right, and omitting the name means "the current commit", aka `HEAD` or `@`.)  So there are two ways to get around this:

- start the exclusion with the commit(s) *before* this commit, or
- use a flag that tells the command *I'd like the commit that would normally be excluded*.

The latter seems simpler, and actually works fine in most cases:

```
git log --boundary --pretty=oneline test-tag..
```

However, `--boundary` behaves badly in some more-complex cases, so I prefer to start the exclusion with the commit's parent(s).

The first parent of any commit is easy to find using the suffix `^` or suffix `~` notation:

```
git log --pretty=oneline test-tag^..
git log --pretty=oneline test-tag~..
```

Both will do just what you want for this particular case, but they too have a slight defect.  You might want to get familiar with this notation despite the minor defects, because it's very handy.  The suffix tilde notation takes an optional number (which defaults to 1), and it counts back that many first-parents.

You didn't show the actual commit hash IDs of your four commits, so let me use a random old repository of my own:

```
$ git log --oneline -n 4
11ae6ca (HEAD -> master) add run-checks script
d1574b8 mxgroup.py: sort-of-mutual-exclusive-groups
b9491ea gerrit-review.sh: push to refs/for/
676699a wacky.py - replacing class-member functions
```

None of these commits are tagged, so let's count backwards from `HEAD` / `master` / `@`:

- `@~1` means commit `d1574b8`, one step back
- `@~2` means commit `b9491ea`, two steps back
- `@~3` means commit `676699a`, three steps back

and so on.

#### More detail (read when ready, the above is sufficient for some time)

The hat or caret (`^`) suffix can also take a number, but this is only meaningful when the commit in question is a *merge commit*.  A merge commit is any commit with *more than one parent*, typically two from using `git merge` to merge two branches:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here, the names `branch1` and `branch2` denote commits `J` and `L` respectively.  (Here `J` and `L` in turn stand in for actual big ugly hash IDs.)

Suppose we run `git checkout branch1` and then `git merge branch2`.  Git will walk backwards from both branch-tip commits, first one step to `I` and `K`, then two steps from each to `H`.  Commit `H` is on *both* branches, and is the best shared commit *before* the two branch tips, so it is the merge base for the merge operation.

Git will then compare all the files in commit `H` to all of those in commit `J`, to see what work someone did on `branch1`.  Separately, Git will compare all the files in `H` to those in `L`, to see what work someone did on `branch2`.  The merge operation then *combines* these changes, applying the combined changes to the files in `H`.  If all goes well, Git makes a new commit, using the files that have *both* sets of changes applied, i.e., has merged the two lines of development.  The new commit looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- ??? (what name points to M?)
         \    /
          K--L
```

New commit `M` gets a new hash ID, different from every existing and future commit.  *Some* branch name must now be updated to remember new commit `M`.  The actual branch name that's updated depends on whether you did `git checkout branch1; git merge branch2`, or `git checkout branch2; git merge branch1`.  Whichever branch you checked out, *that* name gets moved, and the other one stays in place.  We said above that we suppose you do a `git checkout branch1` so let's move the name `branch1` to point to new commit `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Since new commit `M` remembers *two* previous commits, not just one, we now have an interesting couple of cases.  One of the two is the *first parent* of `M`: in this case, that's commit `J` because the name `branch1` used to point to `J`.<sup>1</sup>  So `M~1` and `M^1` means commit `J`: the *first* of the two parents of `M`.

To find commit `L`, the *second* parent of `M`, you cannot use the `~` suffix.  You must use the `^` suffix instead, and write `M^2`.  That tells Git: *find commit M, then find its **second** parent.*

So this is where the `^` suffix becomes more useful than the `~` suffix.  Otherwise, the `~` suffix is more useful than the `~` suffix, because you can count back.  Note, though, that you can combine suffixes: `M^2` gets you commit `L`, and `M^2~` gets you `L`'s parent `K`.  `M^2~2` gets you `K`'s parent `H`, which you could also get to by using `M^1~2`, or just `M~3`: start at `M` and go back three steps, using the first-parent whenever there's a choice.

---

<sup>1</sup>If we do the merge the other way around, so that `branch2` points to `M`, its first parent is `L`, and the second parent is `J`.  Other than which parent is first and which branch name changes, the merge process is often totally symmetric.

---

#### Including a merge commit with the two-dot notation

Suppose we continue on with the `branch1` setup we have at this point, either writing down `M`'s hash ID, or setting a tag to remember `M` for us:

```
          I--J   ..... tag: test-merge
         /    \ .
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Then we go on to make a few more commits:

```
          I--J   ..... tag: test-merge
         /    \ .
...--G--H      M--N--O   <-- branch1
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

What if we'd now like to `git log` commits `M` through `O` inclusive?  Our usual trick of writing:

```
git log test-merge^..
```

doesn't work, because `test-merge^` means *find commit `M`, then step back to its first parent `J`, and exclude `J` (and earlier)*.  The result is that you see `K-L-M-N-O`: five commits, where you expected three.

If you try:

```
git log test-merge^2..
```

you are telling Git *find commit `M`, then step back to its second parent `L`, and exclude `L` (and earlier)*.  The result is that you see `H-I-M-N-O`: five commits, again.

To see this visually, draw the graph above.  Mark the *excluded* commit with a red highlighter.  Keep your red going, marking all the earlier commits you can get to by working backwards.  Then, mark the first *included* commit with a green highlighter.  Keep your green going, marking all the earlier commits you can get to by working backwards, but stop when you reach red-marked commits.

The way to get just the three commits you want—other than `--boundary`, which sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't—is to tell Git: *exclude commit `J`, **and** exclude commit `L`*.  You can do this by not using the two-dot notation:

```
git log ^M^1 ^M^2 HEAD
```

The *prefix* `^` here tells Git: *not*.  So `git log` is to start at `HEAD` and work backwards, but *exclude* `M^1` and also `M^2`.

#### The right answer

Of course, this only works because `M` has exactly two parents.  We list *both* of them as "don't show this commit, nor anything earlier" and we get what we want.  But if we pick a non-merge commit, the `^<commit>^2` fails because there is no second-parent.  What we need here is a notation that says *all the parents of commit `M`*.

It turns out there is just such a notation.  It (and many others) are listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), and this particular one is spelled with the suffix `^@`.  So we get what we want with:

```
git log test-merge^@..
```

This works regardless of how many parents the selected commit has: we exclude *all* of them, while keeping the commit itself.

(There's a relatively new `^-` suffix, introduced in Git 2.11, too.  These documentation pages are worth re-reading occasionally.)

Comment: Thanks @torek!! Worked perfectly.